# MKOverlayView Performance Issue. Doing nothing. But slow

Tags: ios, performance, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I tested on iPad with below code.

If I add MyOverlay like below code, MKMapView loading of default map tiles become slower even though doing nothing in drawMapRect.

And If I remove MyOverlay from MKMapView, the loading of default map tiles become fast again.

I wonder what is done in background when drawMapRect is called.

Or below code has any problem for performance?

[code]

```
@implementation MyOverlay

-(id) init 
{
  self = [super init];

  boundingMapRect = MKMapRectWorld;
  boundingMapRect.origin.x += 1048600.0;
  boundingMapRect.origin.y += 1048600.0;

  coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);

  return self;
}

...
@end


@implementation MyOverlayView

- (id) initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];

  ...  
  return self;
}

- (BOOL) canDrawMapRect:(MKMapRect) sm zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale 
{
  return true;
}

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext: CGContextRef)context
{
  return; // do nothing, but map loading become slower 'much'.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the MKOverlayView's drawing method `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` reminds me of the UIView's `drawRect` method. And MKOverlayView is a subclass of UIView. UIView's subclasses provides this warning:

```
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/
```

If this is still a concern, you should have a look at this SO question, about `drawRect`'s performance: [to drawRect or not to drawRect (when should one use drawRect/Core Graphics vs subviews/images and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14659563/713503)