# Custom UIView or UIControl draw text vs label?

Tags: ios, uiview, subclassing, uicontrol

I'm finishing up a custom UIControl. I need to show some text on the control, but I am not sure what is better praxis: add a label as a subview or draw the text inside the **drawRect** method. I've seen both methods, but I'm unsure what is better implementation praxis. The text doesn't need to be formated, just plain text would do fine.

Comment: have you seen this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659563/to-drawrect-or-not-to-drawrect-when-should-one-use-drawrect-core-graphics-vs-su

Comment: I didn't. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are just fine. However you have better maintenance/control over a UILabel then your drawRect: method. 
You can access the label from outside sources and update it whenever you want without the need to call a updateLayout function (a trigger to call the drawRect).

So I advice you to use a label.

Comment: it has a performance advantadge, then?. The thing is I only need to update the text from within the control, not from a view controller

Comment: Well, the drawRect: function will redraw your entire UIControl whilst updating a label doesn't require that. However if the only time you set a text into the control (and never change it). DrawRect: might be a small performance gain. However the effort isn't worth the gain imo.