# Image Rendering swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, background-process

I am rendering an a lines on UIView. Problem is when I zoom in view, it gets blurred. I want to maintain the clarity while its getting zoom. Can this be achievable through rendering image in background? If yes then how? I am stuck at this part.[[image: When zoomed[1]]
[image: Normal]

below is code for drawing lines :

```
 override  func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        for stroke in strokePoints
        {
            //print(stroke.startPoint,stroke.endPoint)
            path.move(to: stroke.startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: stroke.endPoint)
        }
        shape.path = path
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code on how you draw the lines in the view?

Comment: Edited the question. Please check

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "zoom" the view?

Comment: I mean to say , when I zoom in the drawing which is on the view, its not clear

Comment: You should definitely not use draw(_ rect:) to do that.

Comment: @VinGazoil am I missing something in drawing lines?? Could you please suggest document or links to look up on

Comment: @blueWings The problem with your code is that it will add a sublayer to your layer every time the method gets called. Moreover, `DrawRect(_ rect:)` should only be used for actual drawing (take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659563/to-drawrect-or-not-to-drawrect-when-should-one-use-drawrect-core-graphics-vs-su] for more informations).

Comment: @VinGazoil thank you. Appreciated